# Multipart form data body is empty using NestJS and Fastify

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, multipart, fastify

We are migrating from `express` to `fastify` in our `nestJS` application. The `multipart form data`(json body not files) which were supported in post controllers are not working after migration. We have `typeorm`, `swagger` as well plugged in. Any help is appreciated. Please find below code,

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const { AppModule } = require('./app.module');
  const adapter = new FastifyAdapter({
    logger: true,
  });

  await adapter.register(fastifyMultipart, {
    limits: {
      fieldNameSize: 100, // Max field name size in bytes
      fieldSize: 1000000, // Max field value size in bytes
      fields: 10,         // Max number of non-file fields
      fileSize: 100,      // For multipart forms, the max file size
      files: 1,           // Max number of file fields
      headerPairs: 2000,   // Max number of header key=>value pairs
    } 
  });

  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    adapter,
  );
  await app.init();
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(multer({ dest: './public/uploads/' }).single('file'));

  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Test API')
    .setDescription('Test Identity management')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
  SwaggerModule.setup('testapi', app, document);
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0');
}
```

And the controller code is,

```
    @Post('/Test/V2')
    @ApiOperation({ description: 'test' })
    @ApiResponse({ status: 200 })
    public async Test(@Request() req, @Body() requestDto: RequestDto, @Response() response) {
}
```

Library versions are below,

```
@nestjs/axios: "0.0.3",
@nestjs/common: "^8.2.0",
@nestjs/core: "^8.2.0",
@nestjs/jwt: "^8.0.0",
@nestjs/passport: "^8.0.1",
@nestjs/platform-express: "^8.2.0",
@nestjs/platform-fastify: "^8.2.0",
@nestjs/swagger: "^5.1.4",
@nestjs/testing: "^8.2.0",
@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2"
```

Comment: Is the `multer` you're using fastify's version of `multer` or just regular `multer`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel tried both versions. But did not help. If i use fastify's version, i get "Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined". But no controller/interceptor/guards codes are hit. This particular error coming from fastify library.

Comment: Stacktrace->{"level":50,"time":1636538080461,"pid":16472,"hostname":"host","reqId":"req-1","req":{"method":"POST","url":"/api/API","hostname":"localhost:3000","remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1","remotePort":65142},"res":{"statusCode":500},"err":{"type":"TypeError","message":"Cannot read property 'headers' 
of undefined","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined\n    at hasbody (type-is\\index.js:93:14)\ at Object.typeofrequest [as default] (type-is\\index.js:127:8) at multerPreHandler (\\node_modules\\fastify-multer\\src\\lib\\make-prehandler.ts:28:12) at Holder.done

Comment: @Raj -  so can u try testing a sample endpoint (not a specific one of urs). You can check out this link -  https://github.com/vijayakumar-psg587/nestjs_fastify_upload.git , Please use branch - feature/FASTIFY_MULTER. My bad I should have made that as default. Let me do that

Comment: I believe with the usuage of the specific package , u should be able to see the http req being routed first to the interceptor. The one I used is my custom interceptor to validate the JSON part. I believe I faced a similar issue, but resolved using nestjs-fastify multer module rather than using express specific one.  @webundsoehne/nest-fastify-file-upload . I developed this for my learning purposes, hence the readme.md files are not updated. Will get that updated